# How to implement partials for the content of bootstrap navbar options

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, partial-views

I just started a few hours ago with bootstrap and need to know how to implement/use partials to avoid adding the navigation bar to every page

I have used partials in ruby and .net web site (or master pages) and need to achieve this with boostrap

Maybe this is very basic, but I have searched without much success

Comment: I'll do it with AngularJS: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp, or pure JavaScript if you don't want to include whole library to achieve this.

Comment: @MatjažMav that means that bootstrap does not include a out-of-the-box solution for this ?